# Why won't my method work unless called from a button click?

Tags: c#

I posted this question yesterday, but I don't think i gave enough information to get a definate answer. So here it is again with additional code which hopefully will make things clearer.

I have a form with a listView, which is populated by calling the showCheckedInFiles() method. The method works perfectly fine when I add a simple button to the form and press it, which calls the method, but when I call the method from elsewhere it will not populate my listview.

Please help it's driving me insane. The first method below is called from another class and that is shown underneath this, and I've included the button method as well for reference, as I say, the button works perfectly, but i need to be able to call the method without clicking a button!!:

```
public void openProject(string projectname)
{
    projectName = projectname;
    string userDir = CSDBpath + projectname + "\\checkedOUT\\" + userName;
    if (!Directory.Exists(userDir)) //Does the user's directory exist, if not, create it
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(userDir);
    }
    showCheckedInFiles();
 }

 private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    showCheckedInFiles();
 }
```

The method which calls the above:

```
private void buttonOpenProject_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection mySelectedItems;
     mySelectedItems = listView1.SelectedItems;
     Form1 mainform = new Form1();
     string myProject = "";

     foreach (ListViewItem item in mySelectedItems)
     {
         myProject = item.Text;
     }

     mainform.openProject(myProject);
     //mainform.showCheckedInFiles();
     this.Close();
 }
```

And this is the actual showCheckedInFiles() method which won't build my listView unless called from the button_3_click method .... which i don't want!

```
public void showCheckedInFiles() // ListView1 - load the DMs into the listView to create the list
        {
            listView1.Items.Clear(); // this clears the list of files each time the method is called preventing the list from being duplicated over and over - (refreshes it) !!
            string[] checkedINfileList = Directory.GetFiles(CSDBpath + projectName, "*.sgm", SearchOption.AllDirectories); //JAKE I'VE ADDED THE EXTRA ARGUMENTS HERE and removed \\CheckedIN, MAY NEED TO DELETE FROM .SGM ETC


            foreach (string file in checkedINfileList)
            {


                ListViewItem itemName = list1.getName(file); // get this information from the files in the array
                long itemSize = list1.getSize(file);
                DateTime itemModified = list1.getDate(file);


                listView1.Items.Add(itemName);          // now use that information to populate the listview
                itemName.SubItems.Add(itemSize.ToString() + " Kb");
                itemName.SubItems.Add(itemModified.ToString());


                // readFromCSV(); //Reads the data to the CSV file using the method


                //  // StringBuilder sb = ReadingListView(); //writes the data to the CSV file
                //  // fileWrite.writeToCSV(sb);
                showStatus(itemName);


            }
            showMyCheckedOutFiles();

        }
```

Comment: how is this defined in your code `projectName` in this line `projectName = projectname;` also have you debugged this code at all..?

Comment: When you single-step through the showCheckedInFiles() that doesn't work, does it seem to add everything to the list correctly?

Comment: is showCheckedInFiles() called from the UI thread? Perhaps you're running into a invoke issue.

Comment: You need to show us the calling code that does *NOT* work.  That's where the problem is.

Comment: What does "my method doesn't work" even mean?

Comment: if your are calling another your method from another page then you can call your method on the page_onload method which will enable you to run your method when the page loads without pressing a button

Comment: it means that your method works his doesn't lol

Comment: **Usually**, if you have more information to add to your question, or you want to re-phrase things, you should use the `edit` link, rather than posting a *new* question. (However, your old question had quite a few close votes, so I just went and pushed it over the edge).

Answer (score 2):

It could be that the reason `showCheckedInFiles` fails is not due to where it's NOT being called from, but due to where it IS being called from.  You could tell us some more about that.

In the meantime, my guess is you're calling it before the listView's handle has been created (so the list doesn't really exist yet), or maybe you're calling on a different thread (but you'd most likely see an exception in that case).

Comment: Hard to tell what his actual flow is but looking at the code I have noticed several issues and or questions that could be raised..

Answer (score 0):

buttonOpenProject_Click() does not appear to call anything to display the mainform that it creates. I can't see any way that you would be able to see it!

Comment: So tell me which bit of showCheckedInFiles() is going to display the form that he created? Where is the call to Form.Show()? It *might* be in one of the other methods that is called, but who knows?

Comment: Exactly .. poorly structured question that's why I never post an answer without all the pertinent information I am just saying..

Comment: Which is why I said "does not appear to" rather than "does not"... My reply should at least cause him to go and check, and report back with more information (I hope...)

Comment: Aha I see you are correct Matthew I will remove my comment just noticed that myself..my bad

Comment: Thanks guys, actually i do not REALLY want to create a new form1 called mainform. What i want to do is pass the myProject variable back to a method in the main form which is already loaded. I think this is the problem. As you can tell i'm a complete novice and this is my first proper application. Can somebody tell me please how i can avoid having to create a new instance of form1 and still pass myProject back to the Form1 class?